# GoalSeek Method of Range class failed

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to implement the GoalSeek method using a macro which would run automatically whenever there is any change in the worksheet. The code is simple, but getting this error message, which I can not figureout how to solve. The code is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
   CheckGoalSeek
End Sub

Private Sub CheckGoalSeek()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("MAIN")

   ws.Range("N45").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=ws.Range("D49")

End Sub
```

where "N45" is a formula based cell and "D49" is a value. I am getting the runtime error message "GoalSeek method of Range class failed".

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `GoalSeek` will force a worksheet calculation, it will fire the `Worksheet_Calculate` event, which will invoke `CheckGoalSeek`, which will perform a `GoalSeek`, which will force a worksheet calculation, which will fire the `Worksheet_Calculate` event, which will invoke `CheckGoalSeek`, which will perform a `GoalSeek`, which will force a worksheet calculation, which will ....

To avoid this circular flow, you need to disable Event processing.

Change your `Worksheet_Calculate` function to:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    CheckGoalSeek
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Disclaimer:  The first time I tried this it locked up my copy of Excel.  The second time I tried it it worked.

Comment: This worked! But now a new problem started. Even though the Excel Calculation option is set to Automatic, I have to click on "Calculate Now" button to make things work. Is there any command I can include to avoid this?

Comment: @Amitava - that code should not have interfered with Automatic calculation.  It was happily automatically calculating in my test workbook.  (I just had a simple formula in N45 saying `=D49-1`, and played with it by entering new values in D49 - and the macro constantly changed D49 back to 1.)